# Issue with gradient descent implementation of linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, least-squares, gradient-descent

I am taking [this Coursera class](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-regression) on machine learning / linear regression.  Here is how they describe the gradient descent algorithm for solving for the estimated OLS coefficients:

[image]

So they use `w` for the coefficients, `H` for the design matrix (or features as they call it), and `y` for the dependent variable.  And their convergence criteria is the usual of the norm of the gradient of RSS being less than tolerance epsilon; that is, their definition of "not converged" is:

[image]

I am having trouble getting this algorithm to converge and was wondering if I was overlooking something in my implementation. Below is the code. Please note that I also ran the sample dataset I use in it (`df`) through the [statsmodels regression library](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/regression.html), just to see that a regression could converge and to get coefficient values to tie out with.  It did and they were:

```
Intercept    4.344435
x1           4.387702
x2           0.450958
```

Here is my implementation. At each iteration, it prints the norm of the gradient of RSS:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

# First define the grad function: grad(RSS) = -2H'(y-Hw)
def grad_rss(df, var_name_y, var_names_h, w):
    # Set up feature matrix H
    H = DataFrame({"Intercept" : [1 for i in range(0,len(df))]})
    for var_name_h in var_names_h:
        H[var_name_h] = df[var_name_h]

    # Set up y vector
    y = df[var_name_y]

    # Calculate the gradient of the RSS:  -2H'(y - Hw)
    result = -2 * np.transpose(H.values) @ (y.values - H.values @ w)

    return result

def ols_gradient_descent(df, var_name_y, var_names_h, epsilon = 0.0001, eta = 0.05):
    # Set all initial w values to 0.0001 (not related to our choice of epsilon)
    w = np.array([0.0001 for i in range(0, len(var_names_h) + 1)])

    # Iteration counter
    t = 0

    # Basic algorithm: keep subtracting eta * grad(RSS) from w until
    # ||grad(RSS)|| < epsilon.
    while True:
        t = t + 1

        grad = grad_rss(df, var_name_y, var_names_h, w)
        norm_grad = LA.norm(grad)

        if norm_grad < epsilon:
            break
        else:
            print("{} : {}".format(t, norm_grad))
            w = w - eta * grad

            if t > 10:
                raise Exception ("Failed to converge")

    return w

# ########################################## 

df = DataFrame({
        "y" : [20,40,60,80,100] ,
        "x1" : [1,5,7,9,11] ,
        "x2" : [23,29,60,85,99]         
    })

# Run
ols_gradient_descent(df, "y", ["x1", "x2"])
```

Unfortunately this does not converge, and in fact prints a norm that is exploding with each iteration:

```
1 : 44114.31506051333
2 : 98203544.03067812
3 : 218612547944.95386
4 : 486657040646682.9
5 : 1.083355358314664e+18
6 : 2.411675439503567e+21
7 : 5.368670935963926e+24
8 : 1.1951287949674022e+28
9 : 2.660496151835357e+31
10 : 5.922574875391406e+34
11 : 1.3184342751414824e+38
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
......
Exception: Failed to converge
```

If I increase the maximum number of iterations enough, it doesn't converge, but just blows out to infinity.

Is there an implementation error here, or am I misinterpreting the explanation in the class notes?

### Updated w/ Answer

As @Kant suggested, the `eta` needs to updated at each iteration. The course itself had some sample formulas for this but none of them helped in the convergence. [This section of the Wikipedia page about gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Description) mentions the [Barzilai-Borwein approach](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~wotaoyin/math164/slides/wotao_yin_optimization_lec09_Baizilai_Borwein_method.pdf) as a good way of updating the `eta`. I implemented it and altered my code to update the `eta` with it at each iteration, and the regression converged successfully. Below is my translation of the Wikipedia version of the formula to the variables used in regression, as well as code that implements it.  Again, this code is called in the loop of my original `ols_gradient_descent` to update the `eta`.

[image]

```
def eta_t (w_t, w_t_minus_1, grad_t, grad_t_minus_1):
    delta_w = w_t - w_t_minus_1
    delta_grad = grad_t - grad_t_minus_1

    eta_t = (delta_w.T @ delta_grad) / (LA.norm(delta_grad))**2

    return eta_t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try decreasing the value of eta. Gradient descent can diverge if eta is too high.

Comment: I did but it did not work.  However I am definitely seeing improvements.  Is the choice of eta (as well as epsilon) very much an art?  If so how often is gradient descent really used in practice?  It seems kind of unstable (unless I am doing it wrong, which is quite possible given my question.)

Comment: Decrease eta aggressively. Too small an eta will slow down convergence but will solve the problem you are seeing. There could be some other bug in your program as I have not looked at your code carefully. Choice of eta is an art as the right choice often depends on the nature of the function you are trying to minimize.

Comment: You were right - eta should be decreased at each iteration.  I found a nice formula for doing that in the Wikipedia article about gradient descent and it worked.  I will update my question to show it.